# CDO not sending internal mails

Tags: c#, email, smtp, cdo.message

I am using CDO from sending emails. 
It is the only way I found that works from a certian customer. Standard smtp sending does not

the problem with this method is that it works ok for external email recipients but not for the internal ones.

```
    CDO.Message oMsg = new CDO.Message();
    CDO.IConfiguration iConfg;
    iConfg = oMsg.Configuration;
    ADODB.Fields oFields;
    oFields = iConfg.Fields;
    ADODB.Field oField = oFields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"];
    oField.Value = 2;
    ADODB.Field oServer = oFields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"];
    oServer.Value = Server;

    oFields.Update();
    oMsg.Subject = subject;
    oMsg.From = Sender;
    oMsg.To = recipient;
    oMsg.HTMLBody = body;
    oMsg.Send();
```

Hope someone has an idea
The code does not break
it just does not send an emal.

Can I get an error from the object somehow?

Comment: Try sending a simple text email and see if it works. You are sending an html message which may get blocked.

Comment: tryed and still same

Comment: What email server are you using?  Are you using same server for both internal and external.  Are you sending more than one email with same instance?  is first being sent but not rest?  I found an interesting article but it is from 1999.  Not sure how applicable it is.  Se : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978636.aspx#collabdataobjs_topic3

Comment: looks like it is working fine if I run the same code from a sample command line app. But it does not send local mails when I run it from an WCF web service. For reasons it works for external mail recipients from the WCF as well

Comment: I assume all on the same PC.  Are you running the service from VS or just starting as a normal service.  Normally services runs with a default credentials and not a user credentials.  See msdn : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555287